# Track changes of a file in GIT with Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, diff

I have a solution hosted in Azure, using Git as my repository.
Now, I want to see changes to some files, and compare their current content, with the content 18 month ago.

In Visual Studio, I know that I can right click a file, any-past the contd select "History" - and from there select a message and "compare with previous".

But I don't want to compare +20 commits one and one, and trace the changes from one to file to another.
I want to select a file, and compare it to the current version.

I know I can copy the content of the old file to a new, and then use a third part software, like "Beyond Compare" to compare them. But I think there must be a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the cumulated changes over a period of time for a file, you can ask the diff tool to compare a revision while filtering with your specific file (with or without space diff, feel free to adapt to your needs)

```
git diff [--ignore-all-space] <SpecificCommitHash> -- path/to/your/file
```

Of course, refering to a specific commit hash is sometimes uneasy, as it requires you to first search for it in your log.

Some will opt alternatively for a date-based approach :

```
git diff [--ignore-all-space] --before="one year ago" -- path/to/your/file
```

But you can also, as mentioned, search the file history to pick the exact commit hash you want :

```
git log --oneline --all -- path/to/your/file
```

then search in the output for the hash you want, and use it as suggested above.